# Python invisible environment variable USERNAME without root

Tags: python-3.x, linux, environment-variables, python-3.8

I wanted to use environmental variables to store some credentials and some other information for security and convenience purposes. I've put some into /etc/environment, source'd it and checked that both variables are visible both to root and normal user:

```
$ cat /etc/environment
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin"
MAIL_PASSWORD="pwd"
USERNAME="un"
$ source /etc/environment
$ echo $USERNAME ";" $MAIL_PASSWORD
un ; pwd
$ sudo echo $USERNAME ";" $MAIL_PASSWORD
un ; pwd
```

Then I started python shell (it was also shown that this behavior persist when I use script and invoke it like `python3 test.py`) and tried to get this variables:

```
$ python3
Python 3.8.6 (default, Jan 27 2021, 15:42:20) 
[GCC 10.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> print(os.getenv('MAIL_PASSWORD'))
pwd
>>> print(os.getenv('USERNAME'))
None
>>>
```

Well, one of them is definitely ok, but another one is hidden somehow. Trying to found out reasons of such behavior I tried the same with root privileges:

```
$ sudo python3
Python 3.8.6 (default, Jan 27 2021, 15:42:20) 
[GCC 10.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> print(os.getenv('MAIL_PASSWORD'))
pwd
>>> print(os.getenv('USERNAME'))
un
>>>
```

And now everything works well.

I'm confused, because this problem is connected with variable name. I tried renaming USERNAME to USER and it did the trick, variable $USER is visible both for python and shell. So it's something wrong with variable name USERNAME, but I can find no information about it in docs.

Could anyone explain the observed results? I can just ignore it, of course, and use another variable name, but it may be interesting to find an explanation.

If it's related, I'm running ubuntu 20.10, this issue was found first with ubuntu 20.04. Python 3.8 version tested only.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/866161/setting-path-variable-in-etc-environment-vs-profile ... especially the sections that explain the purpose of /etc/environment. I honestly dont think that such information as a username or password should go into there. Thats like the opposite of good security.

Comment: `$ sudo echo $USERNAME ";" $MAIL_PASSWORD` is useless to show anything. Variables are expanded before running sudo anyway....

Comment: It doesn't resolve an issue. Using any other source (tried ~/.bash_profile and .env in local directory too) doesn't change the behaviour. The mentioned file was chosen because I was creating a script to be run with cron, and it was the simplest while local debugging. In final version /etc/environment is not used. I just wanna know, why does python's interpretation of envvars depend on their names or what else I don't understand.

Comment: Augh. Yeah, you're right about expansion, thanks. Tried with ```sudo su```, the same effect (visible both in shell and python shell).

Comment: `sudo su <user> echo $USERNAME ";" $MAIL_PASSWORD` is also useless...You may want to read  about how _shell_ works and what does variable expansion and how it works, also about difference between single and double quotes - and when to use single quotes and what do they do. You may try `sudo sh -c 'echo $USERNAME ";" $MAIL_PASSWORD'` to have actually a `sh` child process that expands the variables. Or `sudo -s echo '$USERNAME ; $MAIL_PASSWORD'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Could anyone explain the observed results?

The results can be explained by:

- You did not reboot/re-login/refresh PAM session.
- The `MAIL_PASSWORD` variable is exported in the current shell.
- The `USERNAME` variable is not exported.

> ```
>  $ python3
> ```

You sourced `/etc/environemnt`. The variable `USERNAME` is not exported. It will not be passed to environment of child processes. `python` is a child process. So it does not have the variable set. But `MAIL_PASSWORD` is exported in parent shell, so it is set.

> ```
> $ sudo python3
> ```

`sudo` opens `pam` to run `pam_env` which sources and parses `/etc/environemnt`. The variables are exported by `pam_env`. The variables are thus visible in child processes.

> I wanted to use environmental variables to store some credentials and some other information for security and convenience purposes

Great! So, opinion based:

- If you want your variables to be visible only in PAM sessions (after you login, with a password), then put them in `/etc/environment` or in `/etc/security/pam_env.conf`. See `man environment`. Also this will export variables for all users on your workstation. I say you should rarely or never use `/etc/environment`.
- Recommended for the whole workstation for all Bourne compatible login shells: If you want your variable to be visible in shell login sessions, set it in `/etc/profile`, or best add a file to `/etc/profile.d` if your distribution supports it. Remember to keep POSIX sh compatible syntax.
- Similar, for csh-compatible shells there's `/etc/csh.login` and `/etc/profile.d/*.csh`.
- If you want to set the variable for your user only login shells, use `~/.profile`. For bash-only `~/.bash_profile`.
- Recommended, for single user: to set a variable for any new interactive bash shell, just use `~/.bashrc`

Comment: Thank you. Now I've got an idea about how does it work. The first variable really was exported in ~/.bash_profile (with other value, but it doesn't matter) and it was what lead to different results. And renaming to USER reassigned the system envvar. Going to read more about shell...

Comment: `USER` is set by login, see hhttps://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/76354/who-sets-user-and-username-environment-variables @edit . Pick a unique prefix, like `MY_MAIL_PASSWORD` and `MY_USERNAME` so that your variables do not interfere with other. `USERNAME` looks like a too simple variable name.

Comment: Yes, did it to test and finally understand, what exactly I was doing wrong. Without exporting none of them were visible when a unique name was chosen.